tellg() method returning -1 while reading in a buffer
I am trying to write a code to divide a large text file in smaller chunks of size, one-forth of the original size. I tried to use seekg() and tellg() methods in order to read a chunk of size one-forth of the original and then writing it an output file.
But my code is stuck in loop due to tellg() method returning -1 after a few iterations and I am not able to deduce why?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
class FileWriter {
    private:
        std::ofstream m_OutFile;
        char m_CharBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    public:
        FileWriter(const std::string& filename) {
            m_OutFile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out);
            m_OutFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(m_CharBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        ~FileWriter() {
            m_OutFile.close();
        }

        void WriteToFile(std::ostringstream& oStr) {
            oStr << std::ends;
            m_OutFile << oStr.str() << std::endl;
            oStr.str("");
        }
};
bool directoryExists(const std::string& dirPath) {
        return fs::is_directory(dirPath);
}
bool createDirectory(const std::string& dirPath) {
    try {
        if (!directoryExists(dirPath)) {
            fs::create_directories(dirPath);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating directory: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return false;
}

void fileWriterV2 (std::string inp, std::string out) {
    std::filesystem::path p{inp};
    std::ifstream inputFile(inp);
    if (out[out.size()-1] != '/') out = out + '/';
    if (!inputFile) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
       return;
   }
   inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
   std::streampos fileSize = inputFile.tellg();
   std::streampos chunkSize = fileSize/4;
   std::vector<std::ofstream> outputFiles;
   for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
       std::string outputPath = out + std::to_string(i+1);
       bool created = createDirectory(outputPath);
       if (!created) {
           std::cerr << "Directory creation failed. " << std::endl;
       }
       outputPath = outputPath + "/debug.db";
       outputFiles.push_back(std::ofstream(outputPath, std::ios::binary));
   }
   char buffer[4096];
   inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
   std::streampos startPos = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       std::streampos endPos = (i+1) * chunkSize;
       if(i == 3) {
           endPos = fileSize;
       }
       inputFile.seekg(startPos, std::ios::beg);
       while (inputFile.tellg() < endPos) {
           inputFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
           outputFiles[i].write(buffer, inputFile.gcount());
           std::cout << "Tell: " << inputFile.tellg() << " endPos: " << endPos << std::endl;
           std::cout << "File fail: " << inputFile.fail() << std::endl;
       }
       startPos = endPos;
       outputFiles[i].close();
   }
   inputFile.close();
   FileWriter writer(out);
   std::ostringstream oStr;

  // oStr << inputFile.rdbuf();
   size_t memorySize = oStr.rdbuf()->str().size() * sizeof(char);
   writer.WriteToFile(oStr);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

   std::string inputFilename = argv[1];
   std::string outputFilename = argv[2];
   //fileWriterV1(inputFilename, outputFilename);
   fileWriterV2(inputFilename, outputFilename);
   auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
   std::cout << "File writing complete in "<< duration << " ms" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}


https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg

Once the steam enters a failed state you can't do anything else with it until you call clear

As far as I can see, your code would only work when the input size is a multiple of 4 * 4096.
